# How can I extract clusters from an igraph network?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a data.frame  which looks like this (there are 1135 rows) :

```
         var1   var2  corr
590   OTU3902 K00021 0.832
624   OTU2457 K00076 0.847
770   OTU0939 K00184 0.842
774   OTU0939 K00185 0.818
792   OTU3902 K00209 0.828
1053  OTU2859 K00299 0.803
1127  OTU0001 K00320 0.845
1128  OTU0041 K00320 0.819
1129  OTU1364 K00320 0.850
1130  OTU1891 K00320 0.803
1131  OTU2859 K00320 0.841
1137  OTU2457 K00329 0.845
1409  OTU0939 K00349 0.806
1465  OTU1531 K00366 0.840
1470  OTU1531 K00367 0.847
1474  OTU0001 K00368 0.840
1475  OTU0095 K00368 0.829
1544  OTU3041 K00395 0.820
1729  OTU0939 K00496 0.830
1750  OTU0735 K00508 0.835
```

I use :

```
g <- graph.data.frame(data, directed=FALSE)
plot(g)
```

The network is well created. However, it creates some clusters and I would like to extract each cluster seperately. Is there an option with igraph to get different dataframes (or another kind of vector) : one dataframe will correspond to one cluster?

This is my network. It's a mess I guess, but you can see there are some sub-networks. So, I would like to isolate these sub-networks and get the components of each one in a list/data.frame if it is possible.
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to see in those data frames/vectors? Your `data` is for edges, while clusters are for vertices. E.g., OTU3902 and K00021 from the first row may be in different clusters.

Comment: For example, OTU3902 can be found in several rows. What  I want is that : my network is blend of several groups/clusters (I don't  know  the right term), so I would like to extract each cluster (which are blend of different KO and OTU) in list or data.frame? What I call a group/cluster is a  "sub-network", not linked with other groups.

Comment: It would be best if you included an example output. Now it sounds like you want to find isolated components.

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you wish to find the isolated components of the graph. That can be done with `components` as in

```
components(g)
# $membership
# OTU3902 OTU2457 OTU0939 OTU2859 OTU0001 OTU0041 OTU1364 OTU1891 OTU1531 OTU0095 OTU3041 OTU0735 
#       1       2       3       4       4       4       4       4       5       4       6       7 
#  K00021  K00076  K00184  K00185  K00209  K00299  K00320  K00329  K00349  K00366  K00367  K00368 
#       1       2       3       3       1       4       4       2       3       5       5       4 
#  K00395  K00496  K00508 
#       6       3       7 
# 
# $csize
# [1] 3 3 5 9 3 2 2
#
# $no
# [1] 7
```

showing which vertex belongs to which components, sizes of those components, and the number of components.

Now as to just get a list of vertices by component, we may do

```
split(V(g), components(g)$membership)
# $`1`
# + 3/27 vertices, named, from 7eee8fa:
# [1] OTU3902 K00021  K00209 
#
# $`2`
# + 3/27 vertices, named, from 7eee8fa:
# [1] OTU2457 K00076  K00329 
# ...
```

Or even cleaner,

```
split(names(V(g)), components(g)$membership)
# $`1`
# [1] "OTU3902" "K00021"  "K00209" 
#
# $`2`
# [1] "OTU2457" "K00076"  "K00329" 
#
# $`3`
# [1] "OTU0939" "K00184"  "K00185"  "K00349"  "K00496" 
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. And  according to my input file, do you know up to how many rows igraph can create a network? (The input file I use for this post has 1171 rows, but can I import a file with 1 000 000 rows for example?)

Comment: @Paillou, 3 columns and 1000000 rows for R itself shouldn't be a big problem. Now I'm not sure about igraph, it really depends on how it deals with storing graphs. For instance, a 1000000x1000000 adjacency matrix surely would be a problem. Go ahead and see what happens!